# Best approach for emulating a Xcode 4 style 'header bar' control?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Time again to mimick Apple's standard controls!
 We'd like to add a header bar in our windows that is similar to the ones seen in Xcode, i.e. a something like the old fashioned Placard in the legacy Appearance library that is sitting between toolbar and window content.

Any suggestions what would be the most robust approach?

Ideally you'd wish for something like

```
NSXcodeHeaderBar *hrdBar = [[NSXcodeHeaderBar alloc] init];
[hrdBar setBackgroundStyle: [NSBackgroundStyle NSRoundRectBackgroundStyle]];
[hrdBar drawWithFrame: popUpRect inView: controlView];
[hrdBar release];
```

to benefit from consistent styles.. is there a control that would be a good fit we could abuse for the drawing part?

Or do we need to sample the colors and do our own NSGradient thing?
Potentially with a switch for each major OS revision to keep up with Apple's styles?

Any thoughts appreciated!

Cheers,
Jay

Comment: I'm speaking from opinion here, but I would just pick the color and run with it.  It's different from the normal window gradient anyway, so even if a new version of Mac OS X comes out with a tweaked gradient, it should still fit in fine.

Comment: Good point. I guess I was just hoping that I've overlooked something and Apple is (yeah, right..) already providing some kind of control similar to that header bar.

Comment: FWIW - there's an Open Source `DMTabBar` custom control that provides a tab bar control in Xcode 4 style: [DMTabBar](http://danielemargutti.com/dmtabbar-xcode-4-like-inspector-segmented-control/)

Answer (score 0):

I just did this myself to copy the part above the navigation side panel. I just used grab to copy a 1 pixel wide image of the gradient and then used

```
NSRect      theFromRect = NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
theFromRect.size = theImage.size;
[theImage drawInRect:theFrame fromRect:theFromRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
```

To I did a similar thing to copy the buttons.